# Text keeps pushing the button in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, i have some `<p>` tag and a text in it, and it's positioned to the left of the button. If the text keeps getting bigger, the button keeps being pushed to the right. I want to position all the buttons in the bottom-right corner of every div. Here's my HTML:

```css
#dugme {    
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 15vw;
  line-height: 2vw;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(17, 142, 146);
  text-align: center;
  border: white 2px solid;
}

#dugme:hover{
  background-color: aliceblue;
  color: rgb(17, 142, 146);
}

#stripovi {
  padding-top: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#comic {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(230, 200, 119);
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

}

.naziv {
  font-family: 'Fredoka One', cursive;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container-fluid{
  background-color: rgb(74, 198, 202);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="stripovi">
      <div class="comic w-50">
          <div class="comic-img-top d-flex align-items-center form-group" id="comic">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="slike/c1.jpg" alt="comicbook">
                  <div class="naziv">
                      <p class="col p-2 m-0">Heavy Metal Comic</p>
                      <p class="col p-2 m-0" style="color: rgb(155, 151, 151); text-align: left;">ID:0101</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="dugme">Dodaj</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="comic w-50">
          <div class="comic-img-top d-flex align-items-center form-group" id="comic">
              <div class="thumbnail">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="slike/c2.jpg" alt="comicbook">
                  <div class="naziv">
                      <p class="col p-2 m-0">Deadly Class</p>
                      <p class="col p-2 m-0" style="color: rgb(155, 151, 151); text-align: left;">ID:0101</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="dugme">Dodaj</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

[This is what the buttons look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quvuN.png)As you can see in the second comic, the text moved the button to the right. I want to make the button remain in the same position for every product, and that position would be the bottom right corner of this rectangle.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add
`position: relative` to `comic-img-top`
remove the `id="comic"` and instead use classes. ID should be unique, so you shouldn't repeat it.
Add another custom class to form-group, the container which holds the button.

CSS

```
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
```

This will give you the desired result

```
#comic { // Make this  a class and not an ID if it is going to be repeated
    position: relative;
}

.form-group.new-button-container-class{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}

<HTML>
<div class="form-group new-button-container-class">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="dugme">Dodaj</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver! You have no idea for how long i was struggling, and there's nothing even similiar to my problem on the internet. My last option was to post a question on here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```css
position: absolute;
```

This makes your element stay on a position. Therefore this function is called absolute. The `position` property specifies the type of positioning method used for an element (static, relative, absolute, fixed, or sticky). It's syntax is to be used as `position: static|absolute|fixed|relative|sticky|initial|inherit;`. Or if you like to use the javascript approach:

```js
object.style.position="absolute"
```

For total use change:

```css
 #dugme {    
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 15vw;
    line-height: 2vw;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(17, 142, 146);
    text-align: center;
    border: white 2px solid;
}
```

to:

```css
 #dugme {    
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 15vw;
    line-height: 2vw;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(17, 142, 146);
    text-align: center;
    border: white 2px solid;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now everything you need to do is just align everything right.

Comment: I'm still not that familiar to JS, though i could experiment. This doesn't work, unfortunately, but just makes the problem worse.

Comment: You do not have to use the javascript option. You could just ass the CSS option I listed on top of my answer. EDIT: I've changed my answer. This should work.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this still didn't work. The other guy's comment fixed it, finally. Thank you anyway!